# Why do I need to subtract two from 1 << 64 to get 2^64 - 1?

Tags: c

Every line of the output of this program is equal to 2 ^ `i` - 2, except for the last line, which is equal to 2 ^ 64 - 1.  Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long ONE = 1;
    unsigned long long i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
        printf("%"PRIu64"\n", (ONE << i) - 2);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
0
2
6
14
30
62
126
254
510
1022
2046
...
4611686018427387902
9223372036854775806
18446744073709551615
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure shifting by 64 bits results in undefined behavior. Have you tried shifting 64 bits total, but in multiple steps?

Comment: `unsigned long long i <<= 63; i <<= 1;` works where `unsigned long long i <<= 64;` doesn't - you're right, thanks.  Do you know where I can read more about this?

Comment: The answers already link to helpful resources, so I won't bother to clutter this question up with more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming yout `ULL` type is 64 bits wide, you're into undefined behaviour territory. As per `C11 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators`:

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is **greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand,** the behavior is undefined.

What's *possibly* happening is that the shift value is being reduced modulo 64, and `64 % 64` is zero. Hence, it's just evaluating `ONE - 2` which is wrapping to `264-1`. But, in all honesty, it could just be plucking that result out of the air since UB imposes no real restrictions :-)

Answer (score 5):

You are left shifting 64 to a 64-bit type(`unsigned long long` on your machine), it's undefined behavior.

BTW, `unsigned long long ONE = 1;` is bad coding style, you can simply use `1ULL`.

> **C11 §6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>
> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
> that of the promoted left operand. **If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Bad coding style?  It may be the single worst line of code I've ever read!  In terms of characters to meaningful-content ratio, its about **26:1**

Comment: @abelenky Hey don't blame the guy who didn't design the language keywords.

Comment: It _may_ be bad style but it works fine, the integer promotion rules make it very well defined, and `ULL` _could_ be considered unnecessary code clog. I'd be more worried about a variable called `ONE` especially when you have to change its value to `2` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo That is exactly what I mean, using `ONE` as variable name: in this case a constant may be what is needed. In other cases, a meaningful variable name is needed. Good point on `ULL` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

1ULL<<64 is undefined while shifting by less is defined.

See [Is Shifting more than 32 bits of a uint64_t integer on an x86 machine Undefined Behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499104/is-shifting-more-than-32-bits-of-a-uint64-t-integer-on-an-x86-machine-undefined) for more detail on the language standard.

Answer (score 0):

You reached the bit limit of 64bit (long long). Apparently 2^63 shift left causes a rollover, resulting in 2^0 = 1.

1 - 2 = -1 which, when treated as unsigned (assuming long long) is 2^64-1.

This result is interesting, since a non rollover implementation of shift left would result in 0, instead of 1, which after the substraction would result on 2^64-2.