# How am I supposed to pack and unpack this 64-bit integer?

Tags: c++

I am interacting with hardware that gives me various kinds of data packed away inside arrays of `uint32_t`. Unfortunately, I've forgotten how to interpret one of those as a `uint64_t`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
   const uint64_t x = 123456789123456789ULL;

   // Pack into uint32_t[2]
   uint32_t ar[2] = {};
   ar[0] = x >> 32;
   ar[1] = x & 0xFFFF;

   // Unpack into uint64_t
   uint64_t y;
   y = ar[0];
   y = (y << 32) + ar[1];

   // The output should be the same!
   std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
}

// Output: 123456789123456789 123456786224144149
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be2de3f79576d4f5))

What painfully obvious mistake am I making?

Comment: You are missing a four-letter word - `FFFF` (I mean `0xFFFF --> 0xFFFFFFFF`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't left bit-shift, "<<", for 32-bit integers work as expected when used more than 32 times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401888/why-doesnt-left-bit-shift-for-32-bit-integers-work-as-expected-when-used)

Comment: If they are 32 bits, why are you fooling around with `uint64_t` at all?

Comment: @Jongware: Where am I shifting 32-bit integers?

Comment: @vonbrand: They _are_ 64 bits, and should be interpreted as such. The lower-level comms mechanism packs them into 32-bit chunks, though (as it does with many other various types).

Comment: Okay, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499104/is-shifting-more-than-32-bits-of-a-uint64-t-integer-on-an-x86-machine-undefined then.

Comment: @Jongware: From that Q&A, "shifting a uint64_t a distance of less than 64 bits is completely defined by the standard." And there is no place I'm shifting a `uint32_t`. So I don't see how it answers my question?

Comment: Time for C++14 and digit separators!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Shame they're so ugly :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you can use a variadic macro to already use a notation that's ... just about as ugly. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf or a variadic template xD. `Ox(1234,5678,5678)`. Unfortunately, you can't type letters :(

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: +1 neat trick with the "O" :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are masking x with 0xffff, which is only 16 bits. You need to mask it with 0xffffffff for 32bits, otherwise you will lose bits.

Comment: Why not simply assign it directly? Surely it will truncate the top 32bits.

Comment: @DeadMG You'd at least need a cast, both to silence compiler warnings and to show readers that the truncation is intended. But yes, it would probably be an easier (no counting F's) alternative.

Comment: Instead of merely describing the problem, you should demonstrate it with code, so that the OP can see it in context and try it out with copy/paste.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf to be honest, the explanation is plenty clear and if the OP can't figure out how to amend his sample with this fix, then I wager he shouldn't be meddling with bit-level code in the first place...

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
   const uint64_t x = 123456789123456789ULL;

   // Pack into uint32_t[2]
   uint32_t ar[2] = {};
   ar[0] = x >> 32;
   ar[1] = x & 0xFFFFFFFF;

   // Unpack into uint64_t
   uint64_t y;
   y = ar[0];
   y = (y << 32) + (ar[1] & 0xFFFFFFFF);

   // The output should be the same!
   std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
}
```